# How to write a Tailwind class plugin that takes a palette colour as an optional parameter

Tags: tailwind-css

I have this style:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 0 100px white inset;
```

But I don't want `white` hard-coded in - I want to make a Tailwind plugin in my `tailwind.config.js` called `bg-shadow` that accepts the colour as an optional third argument, like so:

```
<input class="bg-shadow" /> <!-- defaults to white -->
<input class="bg-shadow-primary-500" />  <!-- specify the colour -->
```

Having read through the Tailwind docs on plugins, I am none the wiser as to how to achieve this!

Answer (score 6):

You could do this with a pretty simple plugin using `matchUtilities` and `flattenColorPalette`.

In `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
const plugin = require("tailwindcss/plugin");
const { default: flattenColorPalette } = require("tailwindcss/lib/util/flattenColorPalette");

module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    plugin(({ matchUtilities, theme }) => {
      matchUtilities(
        {
          "bg-shadow": (value) => ({
            boxShadow: `0 0 0 100px ${value} inset`
          })
        },
        { 
          values: flattenColorPalette(theme("colors")), 
          type: "color" 
        }
      );
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: Is there a doc for these extra functions? I find most blogs do this function manually.

Answer (score 0):

After studying [this plugin](https://github.com/GraxMonzo/tailwind-caret-color) (credit where credit's due) I have this now working as follows:

```js
 // tailwind.bg-shadow.plugin.js
const plugin = require("tailwindcss/plugin");

const formatShadow = (color) => `0 0 0 100px ${color} inset`;

module.exports = plugin.withOptions(
    ({className = "bg-shadow"} = {}) => {
        return ({e, addUtilities, theme, variants}) => {
            const colors = theme("colors");

            const caretColors = Object.keys(colors).reduce((acc, key) => {
                if (typeof colors[key] === "string") {
                    return {
                        ...acc,
                        [`.${className}-${e(key)}`]: {
                            "box-shadow": formatShadow(colors[key])
                        },
                    };
                }

                const colorShades = Object.keys(colors[key]);

                return {
                    ...acc,
                    ...colorShades.reduce(
                        (a, shade) => ({
                            ...a,
                            [`.${className}-${e(key)}-${shade}`]: {
                                "box-shadow": formatShadow(colors[key][shade])
                            },
                        }),
                        {}
                    ),
                };
            }, {});

            addUtilities(caretColors, variants("bg-shadowColor"));
        };
    },
    () => ({
        variants: {caretColor: ["dark", "active"]},
    })
);
```

And usage in `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        require('./tailwind.bg-shadow.plugin')
    ],
}
```